# Runaway argument error in IEEE template

Tags: graphics, errors

I am using the template entitled "Preparation of Papers for IEEE Sponsored Conferences \& Symposia", in the overleaf. I have a figure that I was using in an ACM template, without errors, and I want to use that in this IEEE template:

```
\begin{figure}[thpb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=9cm]{figureName.png}
  \caption{Inductance}
  \label{figureName}
\end{figure}
```

But I am getting the following error (the figure was imported from a previous project):

> Runaway argument? width=9cm]{figureName.png}
>   \caption {Inductance of oscill\ETC. Paragraph ended before \Gin@iii was complete.  \par

Can anyone help?

Comment: You have a misplaced brace or bracket somewhere, but as you don't show your code ....

Comment: Yes, @Ulrike . I forgot to put the code (edited now in the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error if you load `graphics` (with s) instead of `graphicx` (with x) and then try to use keyval-syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics} %<- wrong, should be graphicx
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[thpb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=9cm]{example-image.png}
  \caption{Inductance}
  \label{figureName}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

gives

```
Runaway argument?
width=9cm]{example-image.png} \caption {Inductance} \label {figureNam\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \Gin@iii was complete.
```

Solution: load `graphicx`.